# Why my variable starting out of the range that I want?

Tags: excel, vba

So I am creating a database based on one of my sheets in my workbook. So I have 3 sheets, "Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", and "Data". I have a userform that will input information in "Sheet 1" and "Sheet 2". And then all that information will transfer to the "Data" tab. So "Sheet 1" could have like 3 rows of information while "Sheet 2" could have 5 rows. And the information sometimes can change or get deleted.

The problem I am having is that my "rs.Cells(Row.Row,2)" is starting off on the very first row. But I set it up where it will start in a specific range that I want. Why is it starting out of range?

```
Dim rs as worksheet
Dim ws as worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Data")
Dim NextRowD as Long
Dim lastRow as Long
Dim note as Range

lastRow = oWS.Range("A:A").find("No.", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
NextRow = oWS.Range("A:A").find(what:="", after:=Cells(lastRow, 1)).Row
Set note = oWS.Range("A:K").find("COMMENTS")

For Each rs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

If rs.name <> "Data" Then
    For Each rw In rs.Range(rs.Cells(lastRow).Offset(1, 0), rs.Cells(note.Row, 18).Offset(-4, 0)).Rows 'this is where I want the range to start

        NextRowD = ws.Range("A:A").find("", after:=Cells(rankD.Row, 1)).Row

        ws.Cells(NextRowD, 2) = Me.tbCustomer
        ws.Cells(NextRowD, 8) = Me.cbLocation
        ws.Cells(NextRowD, 16) = rs.Cells(rw.Row, 2)****** 'the problem is here

    Next Row

End If
Next rs
```

Comment: What worksheet is `Range(Cells(lastRow).Offset(1, 0), Cells(note.Row, 18).Offset(-4, 0)).Rows` supposed to be on?

Comment: All of these `Range` and `Cells` need to be qualified so you are referring to the correct worksheet. OTherwise they will default to `ActiveSheet` which might not be desirable: `rs.Range(rs.Cells(lastRow).Offset(1, 0), rs.Cells(note.Row, 18).Offset(-4, 0)).Rows` (this is just an example, I'm just assuming it is `rs`). Also, consider using a variable name besides `Row` as that is already an object name in the Excel library. It's probably fine the way you are using it here, but it could lead to strange issues.

Comment: @BigBen so that worksheet is based on activesheet. So I can have multiple tabs, and each tab the format of the sheet is the same. And I am pulling data from those tabs into a master sheet called "Data".

Comment: @JNevill so would I need to create a variable that can look at the range for each sheet? How would I do that?

Comment: I wouldn't use a variable like `row` as `row.row` doesn't read very well

Comment: @Phiking That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that if you just say `Range()` without qualifying with the specific sheet for which you intend that `Range()` to be used, VBA will assume you meant `ActiveSheet.Range()`. Which may not be what you meant. You need to qualify your `Range()` and `Cells()` objects so that VBA knows which worksheet you are talking about when you say `Range()` or `Cells()`. In this case: Which worksheet did you want your `rw` iteration to refer to? That's the worksheet you should qualify these objects with.

Comment: @jNevill gotcha,

Comment: @JNevill so I have information at row 14, but my rw is reading at row 2 first. I want the rw to start at row 14 and then move on to 15, 16 and so on. But then on the next sheet, it would read at 14 again. Hope I am making sense.

Comment: `rs.Cells(lastRow).Offset(1, 0)` doesn't look right either - not sure what this would return.

Comment: @SJR That one is the range. So I have it where that part would look for "No." and the offset would look at the range 1 row below that.

Comment: But if `lastrow` is the value 15 which cell would you expect that to refer to? You probably should have a row and column reference.

Comment: @SJR no, so that the range that I want it to be in. So lastrow is the range that I want my rw to be in. So let's say the range is row 14 to row 20. But sometimes I would insert in more row in the middle. So I set it up where the range would be between the offset(1,0) of where the cell "No." is and where the offset(-4,0) of where the cell "Comment" is.

Comment: "no, so that the range that I want it to be in" - sorry, makes no sense. `lastrow` is not a range it is a number (derived from a range). Better practice would be to capture the found cells themselves and then you can refer to them directly (and check the things are found as your code will error if they are not).

Comment: so what I want from rw is that on my master sheet I can reference it. Like on "Sheet 1", the rw is row 14 and the value is 10. It would input that 10 in the master sheet at row 1, column 10. Something like that

Comment: @SJR, lastrow is a variable I made so that it can find the cell "No.". And then use that to find the next blank in a cell. If that makes sense. Sorry, I think I am complaining it a little bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202061/discussion-between-phiking-and-sjr).